# Allowing inactive users to login via custom django backend

Tags: python, django, authentication, backend

I have a custom auth backend that I'm playing with. I want to allow inactive users to log in. Setting the `supports_inactive_user` flag to true doesn't seem to do the trick, even though I can verify that the `user` is being returned.

```
class AuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):

    supports_object_permissions = False
    supports_anonymous_user = True
    supports_inactive_user = True

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        """
        Allow login with email inplace of username

        """
        user = None
        if username is not None:
            username = username.strip()

        if email_re.search(username):
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                pass

        if not user:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None

        if user.check_password(password):
            return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):

        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I'm using django 1.4. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user gets authenticated successfully, but it's the [`AuthenticationForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L134) that raises a `ValidationError` when the user is inactive. You can override the clean method in a subclass to catch the corresponding `ValidationError`:

```
class InactiveAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    # a bit messy but it should work
    def clean(self):
        try:
            return super(InactiveAuthenticationForm, self).clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            if self.cached_user is not None: # user exists but is not active
                # behavior that's skipped because of the validation error
                self.check_for_test_cookie()
                return self.cleaned_data
            else:
                raise e
```

However, consider that a user's `is_active` flag is a replacement for actually deleting the user. You might want to reconsider your use of `is_active`. If you want users to be able to login as soon as they've created an account, there are better ways to achieve that.

Comment: You beat me to it :).

Comment: Haha I'm fast like that :P

Comment: What are the better ways of achieving this? I can't seem to hit anything good on Google on the subject

Comment: @JadS I mean that if you want a user to be able to login, the best way is to just set `is_active = True`.

Comment: I see, but it's not uncommon to see websites where the user can still access  their account before having activated it with the activation link. Is that bad practice?

Comment: @JadS Then the "activation link" is not an activation link, the account is already active. It may be an email verification, but `is_active` isn't meant to validate email.