# How to enable non-superusers login from front end in Django?

Tags: python, django

I've created a view for login but Django only authenticates the superuser. The non-superusers are not able to log in. I only want non-superuser to login from the frontend

```
def logingin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('/signup')

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Can any tell me what modifications I need to do in my codes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing inactive users to login via custom django backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208747/allowing-inactive-users-to-login-via-custom-django-backend)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us how you are crearting the new user (the one that cant login).

You can go to admin panel and check if your password is properly hashed:
[image: see if the password is properly hashed]

If its not, you will se a message:

```
"django Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm"
```

By default, saving form does not hash your password properly. To properly create a user do something like:

```
user = form.save(commmit=False)
user.set_password(user.password)
user.save()
```

Then you're fine :)

Answer (score 0):

your **is_active** flag of non-superusers must be set to false

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active

below is the excerpt

> This doesn’t necessarily control whether or not the user can log in.
>   Authentication backends aren’t required to check for the is_active
>   flag but the default backend (ModelBackend) and the RemoteUserBackend
>   do. You can use AllowAllUsersModelBackend or
>   AllowAllUsersRemoteUserBackend if you want to allow inactive users to
>   login. In this case, you’ll also want to customize the
>   AuthenticationForm used by the LoginView as it rejects inactive users.
>   Be aware that the permission-checking methods such as has_perm() and
>   the authentication in the Django admin all return False for inactive
>   users.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18209379/3053228

Comment: I was trying to set is_active false but that doesn't work. Canyou please show me how to do that? because I think i was not doing it correctly.

Comment: at time of user creation there is flag for is_active, is_staff, is_admin and if you are creating user programmatically then set is_active=false the same way you specify user_name="something"

Comment: @prashant could you please explain exactly where you read that "your is_active flag of non-superusers must be set to false" in the excerpt you posted ??? (hint: that's absolutely NOT what is written nor how it works, quite on the contrary - the mere point of the `is_active` flag is to PREVENT "inactive" users from logging in).

Comment: @mohitchandel you would definitly save yourself quite a lot of pain by reading the doc. My 2 cents...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes I did that and that helps very much thanks!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers somehow I broken the excerpt and combined them wrongly, I meant exactly the same you are pointing out. I have updated the excerpt I hope it make the right sense. when inactive is set to false default backend don't allow user to login, If you want to override this behavior then it needs to be followed

Comment: @prashant it seems like one of us got the question wrong xD. What I understand is that Mohit's issues is that he wants to __allow__ non-superusers to log in but can't get it to work (for whatever reason we can't  say since he didn't provide a [mcve]), and apparently you understood the question as "how to __prevent__ non-superusers to log in" (that's at least the only way I can make sense of your answer). FWIW, note that preventing non-superusers to log in doesn't really make sense - if they can't log in, why have users at all ?-)